# Expressjs homepage says 404 not found but works fine on localhost

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, express

I'm new to expressjs. App works fine on local. I deployed to cpanel and realised after running pm2 start server.js, nothing works. Now I created an htaccess file with below code

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule (.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8081/$1 [P,L]`

Now other pages are showing eg(/products,). But home page is bringing 404 not found. I mean http://xxxxx.com is bringing 404 not found.
Any help, I've searched but couldn't find any solution.

```
const routers=require('./Router')
app.use('/',routers)

Router/index.js

var webRouter=require('./Web')
router.use('/',webRouter)

Router/Web/index.js

const customer=require('./customer');
router.use('/', customer);

Router/Web/customer.js

router.get('/',  (req, res) => {
    res.render('customer/index')
});
```

This code works well on local host

Comment: could you share your routes source code

Comment: @mohammednaji I just edited the question to include details